# change the class of div after fadeOut has been executed on the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which is set to display none using a class.

Now when a button is clicked i want to make the div visible for 5 seconds and make it disappear.

I did like this

```
$("#errorMessage").removeClass("hide").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $("#errorMessage").addClass("hide");
            });
```

The div is visible for 5 seconds and it hides it. When i inspect the div using browser inspector the div has class "hide" itself

No page load is happening. So when i click the button again nothing is happening.

Can anyone please tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is it is because the element has a inlined `display: none` set(`fadeOut()` might be causing it) so after removing the `hide` class make it visible by calling `show()`

```
$("#errorMessage").removeClass("hide").show().delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $("#errorMessage").addClass("hide");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/72R23/), [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/72R23/3/)(doesn't work after first click)